# React vertical timeline component is not showing in the browser

Tags: reactjs, three.js

```
import { VerticalTimeline, VerticalTimelineElement } from "react-vertical-timeline-component"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

import 'react-vertical-timeline-component/style.min.css';
import {styles} from '../styles'
import {experiences} from '../constansts'
import {SectionWrapper} from '../hoc'
import { textVariant } from "../utils/motion"

const ExperienceCard = ({experience}) => {
  return(<VerticalTimelineElement
  contentStyle={{background:'#1d1836', color:'#fff'}}
  contentArrowStyle={{borderRight:'7px solid #232631'}}
  date={experience.date}
  iconStyle={{background: experience.iconBg}}
  icon={
    <div>
      <img
        src={experience.icon}
        alt={experience.company_name}
        className="w-[60%] h-[60%] object-contain"
      />
    </div>
  }
  >
    <div>
      <h3 className="text-white text-[240px] font-bold">
        {experience.title}
      </h3>
    </div>
  </VerticalTimelineElement>)
}

const Experience = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div variants={textVariant()}>
      <p className={styles.sectionSubText}>
        What I have done so far
      </p>
      <h2 className={styles.sectionHeadText}>
        work Experience.
      </h2>
      </motion.div>

      <div className="mt-20 flex flex-col">
        <VerticalTimeline
        layout="1-column-left">
          {experiences.map((experience,index) => {

          <ExperienceCard key={index} experience={experience}/>})}
        </VerticalTimeline>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default SectionWrapper(Experience,"work")
```

vertical timeline component is not showing up in browser it is showing the line for vertical timeline but icon batch and block is not showing up

i thought may be css file is not working so i uninstalled react-vertical-timeline-component and installed it again still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using map method you need to return something you need to remove curly brackets or add return.

```js
import {
  VerticalTimeline,
  VerticalTimelineElement,
} from "react-vertical-timeline-component";
import {
  motion
} from "framer-motion";

import "react-vertical-timeline-component/style.min.css";
import {
  styles
} from "../styles";
import {
  experiences
} from "../constansts";
import {
  SectionWrapper
} from "../hoc";
import {
  textVariant
} from "../utils/motion";

const ExperienceCard = ({
  experience
}) => {
  return ( <
    VerticalTimelineElement contentStyle = {
      {
        background: "#1d1836",
        color: "#fff",
      }
    }
    contentArrowStyle = {
      {
        borderRight: "7px solid #232631",
      }
    }
    date = {
      experience.date
    }
    iconStyle = {
      {
        background: experience.iconBg,
      }
    }
    icon = { <
      div >
      <
      img
      src = {
        experience.icon
      }
      alt = {
        experience.company_name
      }
      className = "w-[60%] h-[60%] object-contain" /
      >
      <
      /div>
    } >
    <
    div >
    <
    h3 className = "text-white text-[240px] font-bold" > {
      " "
    } {
      experience.title
    } {
      " "
    } <
    /h3>{" "} <
    /div>{" "} <
    /VerticalTimelineElement>
  );
};

const Experience = () => {
  return ( <
    >
    <
    motion.div variants = {
      textVariant()
    } >
    <
    p className = {
      styles.sectionSubText
    } > What I have done so far < /p>{" "} <
    h2 className = {
      styles.sectionHeadText
    } > work Experience. < /h2>{" "} <
    /motion.div> <
    div className = "mt-20 flex flex-col" >
    <
    VerticalTimeline layout = "1-column-left" >

    {
      experiences.map((experience, index) => {
        return <ExperienceCard key = {
          index
        }
        experience = {
          experience
        }
        />;
      })
    } <
    /VerticalTimeline> <
    /div> <
    />
  );
};

export default SectionWrapper(Experience, "work");
```